# Can I get a function having a sharp point but its inverse differentiable on its domain.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples, monotone-functions

Suppose $f$ is a function which has a sharp point at $c$ and hence not differentiable at $c$.Can there be found such $f$ which satisfies the above property but is invertible and its inverse is differentiable on its domain?
A related question also occurs in my mind that can I construct a strictly monotone function on $\mathbb R$ differentiable at only one point?

Comment: Depends by what you mean by "sharp point". If you want something like a [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) in mind the answer is no, as it takes the same values on its different sides, and hence has no inverse. If you are satisfied with a function on $[0,\infty)$ only then $\sqrt[3]{x}$ will do it. On $\mathbb{R}$ it has a vertical tangent at $0$, while its inverse is smooth, but it does not look like a cusp.

Comment: Sharp means derivative does not exist only because the 2 sided derivatives do not match but both exist.But it may happen that the limit exists in extended reals but not in reals.I am talking of the case when both side derivatives are different.

Comment: Then the answer is no because the graph of the inverse is the reflection of the original across the diagonal of the first and third quadrants. If the original tangents do not match neither do the reflected ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the last question: No, a monotone function is differentiable almost everywhere.

Comment: You should have written it in comment as it does not fully answer my question.